# Mapping two pure functions over different lists

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, pure-function

Say if I have two lists of vectors of the same length, for example:

```
u = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
v = {{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}
```

I want to add (modulo 2) `u1 + v` and then `u2 + v` and then `u3 + v`, so I want to obtain:

```
u1 + v = {{0,0,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,0}}
u2 + v = {{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,1,0}}
u3 + v = {{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,1,0}}
```

The only way I can do this so far is:

```
Mod[u[[1]]+v[[#]],2]&/@Range[Length[u]]
Mod[u[[2]]+v[[#]],2]&/@Range[Length[u]]
Mod[u[[3]]+v[[#]],2]&/@Range[Length[u]]
```

However, this involves manual/clunky computation. Is it possible to iterate through the positions of `u` as well as iterating through the position of `v`, so that I would be able to calculate this in one go without writing out all the equations?

This is a frequent problem I encounter where I want to define two pure functions to be mapped over different lists in the same line of code. Is it possible?

Comment: Does `Outer[Mod[Plus[##], 2] &, u, v, 1]` do what you want?

Comment: For your current attempt: You can map over the elements of `v` themselves, without having to take the roundtrip over indices: `Mod[u[[1]]+#,2]&/@v`

Comment: @LukasLang That is certainly a better way of doing it! I wonder then if there is a way to iterate through the index of u simultaneously?

Comment: @J.M.'slackofA.I. This is exactly what I was looking to do, thank you! I am still interested as to whether it can be done in the format I'd tried, although my suspicion is that I was just going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Also: `Table[Mod[Plus[u[[i]], v[[j]]], 2], {i, #1}, {j, #2}] & @@ Rest@Dimensions@{u, v}`